# Finding the growth rate of a wave

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I have an equation (from the dispersion relation) for $w$ (frequency) in terms of $a$ (plasma frequency), $k$ (wave vector) and $v$ (velocity of the particles):

$$w^4-(a^2+2k^2v^2)w^2+k^2v^2(k^2v^2-a^2) = 0.$$

1. How to find the wave's maximum growth rate?
2. Why it is imaginary?

According to the given answer, the growth rate of this wave is imaginary and given as $$\Im\left(\frac wa\right)= \frac1{2\sqrt{2}}.$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @ Mon: HINT: $~ x^2- x(1+p) +p (p-1) =0 ~ \text{if} ~ x= (w/a)^2,p=(kv/a)^2;$ What is the symbol of the function whose growth rate is sought?

Comment: An imaginary growth rate means your wave is decaying, i.e. is not unstable at all.

Comment: $1/(2\sqrt 2)$ is not an imaginary number. For any complex number $z$, $\Im z\in\mathbb R$.